# Check for result of verify_recaptcha in Ruby on Rails HTML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

I am trying to get a Boolean result from verify_recaptcha that is implemented my app controller.

Code from the controller:

```
def create
        #render plain: params[:student].inspect
        @student = Student.new(student_params)

        if verify_recaptcha(model: @student) && @student.save
            redirect_to @student
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

HTML code:

```
<h1 class="col-md-12">New Student</h1>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <%= form_with scope: :student,url: students_path,local: true do |form|%>

                  <p>
                        <%= form.label :name %><br>
                        <%= form.text_field :name%>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                        <%= form.label :student_id,'Student ID' %><br>
                        <%= form.text_field :student_id%>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                        <%= form.label :course %><br>
                        <%= form.text_field :course%>
                  </p>
                  <%= recaptcha_tags%>
                  <p>
                        <%=form.submit 'Create Student'%>
                  </p>
                  <%end%>
                  <%= link_to 'Back', students_path %>
              </div>
```

EDIT: Here is what I want to achieve when recaptcha fails.
[image]
So far, when the recaptcha fails, the webpage only reloads and doesn't go to the next page. What I want to do is create an alert indicating the number of errors. It turns out I am unable to use verify_recaptcha in the HTML. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the result of `verify_recaptcha` in the view, you could assign the result to something in the controller, maybe like this:

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)

    @recaptcha_succeeded = verify_recaptcha(model: @student)

    if @recaptcha_succeeded && @student.save
        redirect_to @student
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Now in the view you should be able to refer to `@recaptcha_succeeded`.

However, by passing in a model to `verify_recaptcha`, an error should be added to the model as well, in this case in `@student.errors`.  That information will also be available in the view.  The docs on the recaptcha gem (https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) discuss this in more detail.

Comment: It works now, I was careless and didn't realize that the object.errors is an array. However, it seems a new bug has popped up. The error message "reCaptcha verification failed, please try again" repeats twice.